# Javascript collection that would maintains the order of insertion in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Need to know a Javacript collection that would maintain the order of insertion

I have a scenario where I need to encrypt the data but the third party API accepts an array and returns the encrypted data in a array of same order.

I have a sample Javascript object as below - 
{
"FullName": "Tom Hanks",
"FirstName": "Tom",
"LastName": "Hanks"
}

I need to extract the values and add it to the array as ["Tom Hanks", "Tom", "Hanks"] and the API will return me an array as ["swedfghnjm fgvbh", "ghjn", "gvbhjn"].

I need to map these encrypted data back to the object and send the response.

Is there a way I can achieve this in a correct way?

Comment: Only arrays maintain order, you may want to revisit your logic here.

Comment: Also, are we expected to guess how to decrypt it ourselves in order to answer your too broad/unclear question?

Comment: @AlonEitan He isn't asking how to encrypt or decrypt. The question is only pertaining to the ordering and keeping of said order. Clearly states that in the title.

Comment: @Matt Oh, so `["swedfghnjm fgvbh", "ghjn", "gvbhjn"]` is just some unrelated part. I thought it couldn't be such trivial question, guess I was wrong

Comment: @AlonEitan He is just showing that the return value is still in the same order....just encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Since the array preserves the order, you can manually build the array from the properties' values, then manually build the object:

```js
var obj = { "FullName": "Tom Hanks", "FirstName": "Tom", "LastName": "Hanks" };

var arrToEncrypt = [obj.FullName, obj.FirstName, obj.LastName];

var encrypted = arrToEncrypt; // encrypt

var encryptedObject = {
  FullName: encrypted[0], 
  FirstName: encrypted[1], 
  LastName: encrypted[2]
};

console.log(encryptedObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is maintaining the order for you, so your encryption prep method and your encryption post method just need to assign the properties in the same order

```
prep () {
  arr.push(obj.fullName);
  arr.push(obj.firstName);
}
post() {
  obj.fullName = arr[0];
  obj.firstName = arr[1];
}
```